# SQL: How select rows and minus from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

how construct sql query to select rows from table "Product" and minus sum(pc) from another table "Order".

Here is schema.[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group your orders by the product to get the `sum` of the `pc`-column for the products.

Then `join` the sum onto your `product` table, subtract the sum of the orders from your `pc`-column in the `product` table.

```
SELECT
    product.id_product,
    (product.pc - ifnull(orders.amount, 0))
FROM
    product
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        id_product,
        SUM(pc) AS amount
    FROM
        `Order`
    GROUP BY
        id_product
) AS orders ON orders.id_product = product.id_product
```